# Using the --ignore cli option with babel-node

Tags: babeljs, babel-node

I am trying to set up babel-node for developement, in a monorepo that we are creating. The base folder structure of the monorepo, looks something like this:

```
+ apps
    + app1
      ...
      - package.json
      - tsconfig.json
      - babel.config.js
    + app2
      ...
      - package.json
      - tsconfig.json
      - babel.config.js
    ...
+ packages
    + package1
      ...
      - package.json
      - tsconfig.json
    + package2
      ...
      - package.json
      - tsconfig.json
    ...
- package.json
- babel.config.js
```

Where each `app` and `package` has their separate package.json files, and the main `package.json` file shown in the above directory structure, sets the workspaces (I am using `npm`).

All the apps and packages are written in typescript, and each have their own separate `tsconfig.json` file. What I am trying to achieve, is to be able to run one of the `apps` in developement mode, by transforming and transpiling the code that was written in typescript, using a JIT transformation. For this, I've chose to use `babel-node`.

Each app has a `babel.config.js` file, that loads the core `babel.config.js`, which sets up the following presets and plugins for use:

```
/** This is a plugin written by us, that used with the babel-plugin-module-resolver, should load the tsconfig file appropiate of the package that is importing something, and if finds an appropiate alias, should change the module resolution on the fly **/
const babelResolvePath = require('@yellow-utils/babel-resolve-path-typescript');
const path = require('path');

const [presets, plugins] = [[], []];

presets.push(["@babel/preset-env", {
    targets: {
        node: 'current'
    }
}]);
presets.push("@babel/preset-typescript");

/** We start from the apps tsconfig file that was being loaded **/
const usedTsConfig =path.resolve(process.cwd(), './tsconfig.json');

plugins.push([
    require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
    {
        root: ["./src/"],
        resolvePath: babelResolvePath.createPathResolver({
            tsconfigPath: usedTsConfig, 
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.mustache']
        }),
        extensions: [".js", ".ts"],
        stripExtensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    }
]);

module.exports = { 
    presets,
    plugins
};
```

My problem is the following: all of our tsconfig files are set up, so that when I am importing something in `app1` for example, from `package1`, the import is aliased, so that the file is not loaded from the `node_modules` folder, but directly from the repositories file structure. So basically, if I do in `app1/src/index.ts`

```
import {...} from 'package1';
```

it should be rewritten to

```
import {...} from '../../../packages/package1/src/index.ts`
```

According to the documentation, by default, if you do not provide either `--ignore`, nor `--only` parameters for babel-node on the command line, all files from `node_modules` will be ignored and not transpiled, and ONLY files from the current working directory will be transpiled. This does not work for us, as files that are imported from the `packages` folder should also be transpiled.

I've tried to set an ignore to the babel-node then, so that the `only` rule will be disregarded, but I am failing to achieve any success with this.

These are the commands that I've tried, and the reasons they failed. All commands are run from the scope of one of the app directories, for example, from `apps/app1/`

```
// with this command, babel will try to transpile all node_modules aswell, but the script runs as expected otherwise
babel-node -x .ts,.js --ignore node_modules src/index.ts

// other variations on the above command, trying with "regexp", as the documentation states, achieves the same outcome as before - the files imported from node_modules folder are also transpiled
babel-node -x .ts,.js --ignore=\".*node_modules.*\" src/index.ts

// also tried by supplying a glob pattern, but the results are the same
babel-node -x .ts,.js --ignore **/node_modules/**
```

The only way I was able to achieve my desired result, is by adding the relative path to the node_modules folder that I want ignored:

```
babel-node -x .ts,.js --ignore ../../node_modules src/index.ts
```

However, I feel this to be not portable at all, as if my folder structure changes, I need to constantly update the dev command as well.

What am I missing here? Why is neither the regexp, or the glob pattern working, and why does babel ignore the node_modules folder, when I supply to it neither `ignore` nor `only` cli parameters? According the documentation, the default value for the `ignore` cli parameter is `node_modules`, and the `only` parameter is empty, unless neither the `ignore`, nor the `only` parameter was supplied.

I am not even sure, that this error is originating from `babel-node`, and not from `babel-plugin-module-resolver`, but I couldn't try it out if I am right or not.